# What should I use in react-native/redux fetch instead of Body.text() for non- UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, fetch-api

I am using react native and redux, with redux-thunk, to read XML data using fetch, and almost all works fine.
Here is the code:

```
const parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;

export const fetchData = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_START });

    fetch('https://.../file.xml')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then((response) => {
        parseString(response, function(err, result) {
          fetchSuccess(dispatch, result);
        });
      }).catch((err) => {
        fetchError(dispatch, err);
      });
  };
};
```

However, there are some character strings in the data that are not UTF-8 (probably UTF-16).

I understand that [iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite) can help, and that I should not use it together with Body.text() [since Body.text decodes using UTF-8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text).
There are examples [here](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/issues/150) for how to use iconv-lite with react native and axios, but I am not sure how to use it in my code.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If I Am Not For Myself Who Is For Me :)

The solution is to avoid using fetch (which has other limitations) and use axios (or something similar) instead.

Here is my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import iconv from 'iconv-lite';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
const parseString = require('react-native-xml2js').parseString;

export const fetchData = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_START });

    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://.../file.xml',
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }).then((response) => {
      const result = iconv.decode(new Buffer(response.data), 'ENCODING');
      parseString(result, function(err, data) {
        fetchSuccess(dispatch, data);
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
      fetchError(dispatch, err);
    });
  };
};
```